# Error NullPointerExeception: When trying to add Value in ArrayList & adapter.notifydatachanged

Tags: java, class, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I have setup & initiate an RecyclerView `mainWatchList`, and ArrayList `stockPriceList` in MainActivity `OnCreate()` function, and also have `StockPrice()` function in MainActivity in which I am adding data to ArrayList `stockPriceList`, and using `minWatchList` recyclerView adapter `stockPriceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to refresh the data changed.

I have create 2 RecyclerViews `suggestList & mainWatchList` and when someone clicks itemView of `suggestList` itemView.OnClickFunction is called and It passes the arrayList postion and also calls the `StockPrice` Function.

But at last, When I am trying to run program it shows error that `stockPriceList.add(new defualtWatchListModel(Name, symbol, price));` stockPriceList is null and you can't add into.

Error:[image: Here is the Image of Error]

Code of MainActivity.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    suggestList = findViewById(R.id.suggestList);
    searchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    stockModelClassesArray = new ArrayList<>();

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    suggestList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    suggestAdapter = new stockSuggestAdapter(stockModelClassesArray, MainActivity.this);

    suggestList.setAdapter(suggestAdapter);

    // Setting up Main Activity ArrayList.
    mainWatchList = findViewById(R.id.defaultWatchList);
    stockPriceList = new ArrayList<>();
    mainWatchList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    stockPriceAdapter = new StockPriceAdapter(stockPriceList, MainActivity.this);
    mainWatchList.setAdapter(stockPriceAdapter);
}
```

also in Main Activity StockPrice Function Code:

```
public void StockPrice() {

    String name = Name;
    String Symbol = symbol;
    String price = "$20";

    stockPriceList.add(new defualtWatchListModel(Name, symbol, price));
    stockPriceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

Code From suggestList RecyclerView Adapter in which StockPrice() function have been called:

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView symbol, name, exchange, type;
    public ConstraintLayout listContainer;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

      
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
                stockModelClass positionedStock =  stockModelClassArrayList.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
                mainActivity.OnClickItemViewListener(positionedStock.getName(), positionedStock.getSymbol());
               // Run this one
                mainActivity.StockPrice();

                stockModelClassArrayList.clear();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling the activity's constructor? I'm no Android expert, but I always thought that this is not supposed to be done. You're doing so creates a bastardized activity instance, one who's onCreate is not called, and this will make your ArrayList remain null. The android activity life cycle should call the activity's onCreate method for you, and this is the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps you'll want to pass the needed object(s) into the adaptor via its constructor.

Comment: I just want to add Name, Symbol, Price into the object and then add object into the ArrayList. I am beginner and Learning all this by myself, so sorry if I am doing something wrong please let me know how should I approach it.